# Protocol-driven circuit breaking operator

Tags: python, operators, pep

I came across the term "protocol-driven circuit breaking operator" in [PEP 532](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0532/), and couldn't find what exactly it means.

Can you explain what this phrase means?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, a "protocol" is an API.  And "circuit breaking" might be more easily understood by another phrase, "short circuiting."  As in:

```
if text is None or not text.startswith("lorem"):
    raise RuntimeError("text should exist and start with 'lorem'")
```

Since `text.startswith()` is only valid code if `text` is not `None`, the above code "short circuits" using the `or` operator, which does not bother to evaluate the right hand argument if the left-hand is true.  Similarly, the `and` operator short-circuits if the left-hand is false (because the result then must be false).

So the point of this PEP is to enhance the facilities for building expressions which can short-circuit in more elaborate ways.

Comment: Thanks John for your nice answer. I think in your statement "Since text.startswith() is only valid code if text is not None", you meant to say "... if text is None" (removing "not")?

Comment: @Simplicity: No, what I wrote is correct.  If text is None you can't operate on it.